# query to get the value of a particular cell in Mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a table in mysql like this.

RequestName | Status | Details

Req1        | Scheduled | NA

Req2        | Pending   | Na

Now how can i get the value scheduled?Can you please help me on what query to use to get that value

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `Status` FROM tableName WHERE `RequestName` = 'Req1'
```